# How to swap first and last digits of a number using for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, swap

I need to ask user to input a 3 digit number and then swap the first and last numbers using a for loop. This is what I have so far, but I'm stuck. Using a for loop seems illogical, but that is what I have to do:

```
num = prompt("Please input a number with 3 digits.");
let firstDigit = num[0];
let secondDigit = num[1];
let lastDigit = num[2];

for (firstDigit < 10; secondDigit < 10; lastDigit < 10); {
    console.log(lastDigit + secondDigit + firstDigit);
}
```

Please help!

Thanks

Comment: `for` syntax in your code is not valid check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration

Comment: Is this like a mathematical challenge or something?, It is definitively easier to do it without a loop.

Comment: You have many problems with your code. First, although you can access a string like an array, it's NOT an array, and you can alter values like that. You can convert it to an array and do `[arr[2], arr[0]] = [arr[0], arr[2]];`, but better yet just `num.split('').reverse().join('');`.

Comment: @DanielRodríguezMeza, yes it is...It's stumping me because I can think of much better/easier ways to do this!

Comment: @dangerousmanleesanghyeon, thank you...although I'm still struggling to figure it out!

Comment: @code, Thanks so much, that makes sense, but for this challenge I have to use a for loop...

Answer (score 0):

is it help for you?

```js
// let num = prompt("Please input a number with 3 digits.");

// if (num.length > 3) alert("3 digits please");
// else {
//   let answer = "";
//   for (var i = 2; i >= 0; i--) {
//     answer = answer + num[i];
//   }
//   console.log(answer);
//}

let num = prompt("Please input a number");
let temp = "";
let answer = "";

for(let i = 0 ; i < num.length; i++) {
    if (i === 0) temp = num[i]; // save first number to temp
    else if (i === num.length - 1) {
        // When the last number is encountered, the last number is put at the beginning, and the first number stored in temp is put at the end.
        answer = answer + temp;
        answer = num[i] + answer;
    }
    else answer = answer + num[i];
}
console.log(answer);
```

Comment: Thank you SO much, that worked!! I just don't understand how...Is there any chance you could explain the logic to me? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: For example, what would the code be if input number could be more than 3 digits?

Comment: @Mika9 i just edited answer